# Is Triangulation both qualitative and quantitive?

Tags: ux-field, quantitative-analysis, qualitative-analysis

Quick question: Is Triangulation both qualitative and quantitive?

Comment: Can you provide more details about how this method is used, and what information is collected? I am not familiar with this term in the context of UX design.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is IT DEPENDS. I mean, triangulation is a method or technique that COULD BE USED on both research  methodologies, which doesn't mean that triangulation IS quantitative or qualitative. These are methodologies, while triangulation is an approach to those methodologies (or a technique if you want).

Because of this, triangulation can be used on qualitative research, OR quantitative, or both. This being said, it's most commonly used in qualitative research, specially in UX

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it *depends*. But, triangulation remains a useful tool to use in **qualitative** research, but one should weigh the advantages and disadvantages before application. If researchers decide that triangulation is desired, there are several types of triangulation that can be used:

- Data
- Investigator
- Methodological
- Environmental

Triangulation can be used to deepen the researchers’ understanding of the issues and maximize their confidence in the findings of **qualitative** studies.

> Lisa A. Guion, David C. Diehl, and Debra McDonald

Answer (score 0):

Another "it depends" answer, but since we are in a UX forum, I would say that in most UX cases, "triangulation" pertains to methodological triangulation, rather than data, investigator, or environmental triangulations as mentioned above. So, methodological triangulation does mean a mixed-method research, most often a mix of qualitative and quantitative methods (say, for example, interviews, surveys, and contextual inquiry). The value of triangulation in UX is to obtain as valid and as reliable results as possible, covering important insights to answer your UX problem.